# User defined Quick Build command (sage) does not work in Texmaker

Tags: 14.04, latex, sagemath

I use `LaTex` a lot in Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I came to know about the `sagetex` package and installed `sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux` . Suppose the tex file is `example.tex` , then one  has to run the following commanda to make it work.

```
pdflatex example.tex
sage example.sagetex.sage
pdflatex example.tex
```

Now I want to do run these commands from `Texmaker`. So I go to the menu  and then `Options → Configure → QuickBuild → User` and define there (in User) these three commands. I used the following pipeline

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | sage %.sagetex.sage | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

After that when I run `Quick Build` on the file from texmaker, I get a error message,

```
Error : could not start the command
```

I want to know why the Quick Build command does not work ? also if anyone could help me so that I could run those command from Texmaker.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried StackExchange for `Tex` and resolved the problem. I have figured out whats was going wrong with my `Quickbuild` command. I have to write the whole path for the command `sage` in Texmaker. I replace my pipeline in `Options → Configure → QuickBuild → User` with

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | /home/ddas/sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux/sage %.sagetex.sage | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

But you have to replace the path `/home/ddas/sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux/sage`  with yours.

Also you may write your own script as @Dan advised at [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274815/user-defined-quick-build-command-sage-does-not-work-in-texmaker)